# PostgreSQL UPSERT issue with NOT NULL columns

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I want o know if it's possible to do an upsert when one of the columns (column1 or column2) is null, I just need a partial update, and of course, I'm trying to avoid a `SELECT` to verify if the record already exists.

This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    column1 timestamp NOT NULL,
    column2 uuid,
    status integer NOT NULL,
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT upsert_conflict UNIQUE (id, status)
);
```

And I have something like this:

```
INSERT INTO test(column1, status, id) 
VALUES(now(), 0, <any uuid>)
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT upsert_conflict 
DO UPDATE SET column1= now()
```

This one works as expected, but I also have something like this:

```
INSERT INTO test(column2, status, id) 
VALUES(gen_random_uuid (), 0, <existing uuid>)
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT upsert_conflict 
DO UPDATE SET column2= gen_random_uuid ()
```

I know that the `INSERT` is wrong because we cannot set a NULL value to column1, but assuming that I already have a record with that id and status, I would like to do the `UPDATE`, instead of that, I'm getting an error: `...violates not-null constraint.` because of the missing column.

I'm creating these queries dynamically according to what users pass me. Sometimes I will have something like the first example, and sometimes, something like the second example, and also I don't know which column must not be null.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: If the 2nd case is meant to always do an UPDATE and never an INSERT, why not use UPDATE?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I don't know if I need to do an INSERT or UPDATE, that's why I'm trying to do an UPSERT.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48816629/on-conflict-do-nothing-in-postgres-with-a-not-null-constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example never makes sense, while `column1` is defined `NOT NULL`. You must provide a value for the required column, or the command will fail *before* it can even check for unique violations.

#### Query 1

This query only executes the `UPDATE` part only if either `column1` or `column2` are NULL and at least one actually changes (anything actually changes), but it does not allow to revert either back to NULL:

```
INSERT INTO test AS t
       (column1, column2          , status, id) 
VALUES (now()  , gen_random_uuid(), 0     , '5beb004a-63ec-4f01-8604-37296a208e5f')
ON     CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT upsert_conflict
DO     UPDATE
SET    column1 = COALESCE(t.column1, EXCLUDED.column1)
     , column2 = COALESCE(t.column2, EXCLUDED.column2)
WHERE (t.column1 IS NULL
    OR t.column2 IS NULL)
AND   (t.column1 IS DISTINCT FROM COALESCE(t.column1, EXCLUDED.column1)
    OR t.column2 IS DISTINCT FROM COALESCE(t.column2, EXCLUDED.column2));
```

But `COALESCE()` never kicks in for this particular setup. `column1`, being defined `NOT NULL`, cannot be `NULL`, neither in the table nor in the input `VALUES`. So `column2` *has* to be NULL or nothing happens. Hence we can never reset `column2` to `NULL` anyway.

#### Query 2

This query only executes the `UPDATE` part if either `column1` or `column2` are NULL and at least one is actually being changed -even if back to NULL:

```
INSERT INTO test AS t
       (column1, column2, status, id) 
VALUES (now()  , NULL   , 0     , '5beb004a-63ec-4f01-8604-37296a208e5f')
ON     CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT upsert_conflict
DO     UPDATE
SET    column1 = EXCLUDED.column1
     , column2 = EXCLUDED.column2
WHERE (t.column1 IS NULL
    OR t.column2 IS NULL)
AND   (t.column1 IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.column1
    OR t.column2 IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.column2);
```

This time, actual input values are used, even if NULL. No `COALESCE()` that defaults to the existing value if the new one is `NULL`

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5ae76d7c38b5eddf2b26cca89388af79)*

Either way, you can be sure that a row with `(status, id) = (0, '5beb004a-63ec-4f01-8604-37296a208e5f')` exists after executing the command successfully - even if that row might be missing from the set returned by a `RETURNING` clause. See:

Related:

- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/939860)

Comment: I provided both variants as I am not quite sure what you need exactly after reading the question repeatedly.

Comment: Well, your first comment answers my question. I will have to execute two queries. Thanks